# How to automatically open folder location in package explorer corresponding to the viewed .java

Tags: java, eclipse, package

Suppose I am in Eclipse viewing some `.java` file. Currently all projects in my package explorer are uncollapsed, i.e. they have not been navigated to any of their subdirectories within package explorer.

What I want to do is to find a hotkey which will cause package explorer to automatically open up all directories and sub-directories all the way down to the class that I'm currently viewing.

I want to do this because sometimes I will go to a class through `Call Hierarchy` or `F3` and would like to view its location in its respective package without manually browsing package explorer for it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes you can do this. See the pic below.

[image]

- Open the file in an editor
- Click on **Link with Editor** button in **Package Explorer View**.
- Initially there is no hot key assigned to it. You can assign a hot key for this. Go to Windows > Preferences type **keys** in the top left text box. Ref pic below

[image]

- Here I assigned <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>[</kbd> key to this command. Make sure this key combination is unique and not conflicts with other key combinations.

---

**Note:**

> The bad part is this key is not working if the Package/Navigator view was not active.
>
> So to activate one of these views press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>F7</kbd> then go on pressing <kbd>F7</kbd> key(while holding <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> key) till you reach the Package/Navigator view then release <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> key and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>[</kbd>.